# How to create a special 'combining' enumerator

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have (or will have) a class that returns a sequence of dates (based around a Recurrence pattern). The sequence may have a finite end (# results or an end date) or be infinite.

What I want to do is write a class that will take a list of such enumerators (plus a Start Date) and 'combine' their sequences into one enumerable output sequence ordered by date. It would have to deal with source enumerations ending (or not even starting) and also with multiple source enumerations producing the same Date.

So my question is how can I best achieve this?

More information (if it helps):
e.g.
If I have RecurrencePatterns of:-
(1) "1st of each month, ending 4th July 2017";
(2) "End of each quarter, 6 occurrences only"
(3) "Last day of the Year"
and I start with 1st Jan 2017, I want the output to be:-

1st Jan 2017(1),
1st Feb 2017 (1),
1st March 2017 (1),
31st March 2017 (2),
1st April 2017 (1),
1st May 2017 (1),
1st June 2017 (1),
30th June 2017 (2)
1st July 2017 (1), [(1) - last enumeration because next is after its end date]
30th September 2017 (2),
31st December 2017 (2, 3), [two events with same date]
31st March 2018 (2),
30th June 2018 (2)  [(2) - last enumeration because it only produces 6]
31st December 2018 (3),
31st December 2019 (3),
31st December 2020 (3),
etc.

The actual output of the Recurrence pattern class will probably be some sort of EventInfo class containing the Source and the Date. 
The output of the 'combining' enumerator will be similar but should multiple Recurrence EventInfo have the same date, it would output a single EventInfo with a single Date and a list of sources which return that date.

Comment: Are you saying you want to merge the output of multiple non-terminating enumerations... and sort it?

Comment: Yes to your first question and a 'sort of' to your second question - the sorting would be done on each of the (single) dates returned by each Source - the earliest would then be yielded (and its Source asked for the next in its sequence). Process repeated.

Comment: OK, so you could start by GetEnumerator() on each enumeration, put them in a list, then MoveNext() on each enumerator. In main loop, check Current on each enumerator, return lowest and MoveNext() on the one that had the lowest value, repeat?

Comment: Thanks to both Ed and Jacob - I can now see how to use Current and MoveNext() to achieve the result. Jacob's code was first and had comments but it didn't compile initially; Ed's, only a few minutes later, worked straight off and is slightly cleaner to read. However ( :-) ), neither deal with different enumerators producing the same date. Possibly I didn't explain that clearly initially but the More Information showed 31st December should be output only once. I think the fairest thing is to Upvote both Answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`SortedMerge`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#sortedmerge) in MoreLINQ, if you want duplicates to be returned, or [`OrderedMerge`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#orderedmerge) if duplicates are not desired.

---

Here's how you might write it, if you didn't want to install a NuGet package, or none of the overrides are suitable for your needs.

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> CombineDateTimes(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<DateTime>> list) {
    // keep track of which enumerators are still available
    var eligible = list.Select(l => l.GetEnumerator()).Where(l => l.MoveNext()).ToList();

    while (eligible.Any()) {
        // find the lowest enumerator
        IEnumerator<DateTime> min = eligible.First();
        foreach (var l in eligible.Skip(1)) {
            if (l.Current < min.Current) {
                min = l;
            }
        }

        // here is our lowest
        yield return min.Current;

        if (!min.MoveNext()) {
            // if the enumerator ends,
            // remove it from the list of eligible enumerators
            eligible = eligible.Remove(min);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Answers from Jacob and Ed, I was able to come up with the following code which someone may find useful:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TIPS.UnitTest
{
public class EventInfo
{
    public DateTime Date;
    public EventSource EventSource;
    public List<EventSource> AdditionalEventSources; // Left null if no additional sources
}

public abstract class EventSource
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return GetType().Name; }
    }

    public abstract IEnumerable<DateTime> RecurringDates();
}

public interface IEventInfoGenerator
{
    IEnumerable<EventInfo> GenerateEvents(List<EventSource> eventSources);
}

public class MyAnswerEventInfoGenerator: IEventInfoGenerator
{
    public IEnumerable<EventInfo> GenerateEvents(List<EventSource> eventSources)
    {
        // Combine the Event Sources and their DateEnumerators ignoring any without Dates to return
        var sourceEnumerators = eventSources
            .Select(es =>
                        new
                            {
                                Source = es,
                                DateEnumerator = es.RecurringDates().GetEnumerator()
                            })
            .Where(e => e.DateEnumerator.MoveNext())
            .ToList();

        // Keep going until there is nothing left
        while (sourceEnumerators.Any())
        {
            // Find the earliest date
            var earliestSource = sourceEnumerators.OrderBy(se => se.DateEnumerator.Current).First();

            // Prepare the EventInfo
            var eventInfo = new EventInfo
                                {
                                    Date = earliestSource.DateEnumerator.Current,
                                    EventSource = earliestSource.Source
                                };

            // Remove the EventSource if it has no more Dates
            if (!earliestSource.DateEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                sourceEnumerators.Remove(earliestSource);
            }

            // Quick check to see if there are other EventSources with the same date (no need to create a list if not necessary
            if (sourceEnumerators.Any(se => se != earliestSource && se.DateEnumerator.Current == eventInfo.Date))
            {
                // Yes, there are so create a list for them
                eventInfo.AdditionalEventSources = new List<EventSource>();

                // Go through each 
                foreach (var additionalSourceEnumerator in sourceEnumerators.Where(se => se != earliestSource && se.DateEnumerator.Current == eventInfo.Date).ToArray())
                {
                    // Add it to the EventInfo list
                    eventInfo.AdditionalEventSources.Add(additionalSourceEnumerator.Source);

                    // And remove them if they are spent
                    if (!additionalSourceEnumerator.DateEnumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        sourceEnumerators.Remove(additionalSourceEnumerator);
                    }
                }
            }

            yield return eventInfo;
        }
    }
}


[TestFixture]
public class RecurrenceTests
{
    static IEnumerable<EventSource> CreateTestEventSources()
    {
        yield return new EventSource1();
        yield return new EventSource2();
        yield return new EventSource3();
        yield return new EmptyEventSource();
    }

    static void TestStackoverAnswer(IEventInfoGenerator answer)
    {
        var testEventSources = CreateTestEventSources().ToList();

        foreach (var eventInfo in answer.GenerateEvents(testEventSources))
        {
            Debug.Write($"{eventInfo.Date} - {eventInfo.EventSource.Name}");

            if (eventInfo.AdditionalEventSources != null)
            {
                Debug.Write(", " + string.Join(", ", eventInfo.AdditionalEventSources.Select(ev => ev.Name)));
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestMyGo()
    {
        TestStackoverAnswer(new MyAnswerEventInfoGenerator());
    }
}

public class EventSource1: EventSource
{
    public override IEnumerable<DateTime> RecurringDates()
    {
        yield return new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
        yield return new DateTime(2017, 2, 1);
        yield return new DateTime(2017, 3, 1);
        yield return new DateTime(2017, 4, 1);
        yield return new DateTime(2017, 5, 1);
        yield return new DateTime(2017, 6, 1);
        yield return new DateTime(2017, 7, 1);
    }
}

public class EventSource2: EventSource
{
    public override IEnumerable<DateTime> RecurringDates()
    {
        yield return new DateTime(2017, 3, 31);
        yield return new DateTime(2017, 6, 30);
        yield return new DateTime(2017, 9, 30);
        yield return new DateTime(2017, 12, 31);
    }
}

public class EventSource3: EventSource
{
    public override IEnumerable<DateTime> RecurringDates()
    {
        yield return new DateTime(2017, 12, 31);
        yield return new DateTime(2018, 12, 31);
        yield return new DateTime(2019, 12, 31);
    }
}

public class EmptyEventSource: EventSource
{
    public override IEnumerable<DateTime> RecurringDates()
    {
        yield break;
    }
}
```

}

The output of the Test looks like this:-

```
01/01/2017 00:00:00 - EventSource1
01/02/2017 00:00:00 - EventSource1
01/03/2017 00:00:00 - EventSource1
31/03/2017 00:00:00 - EventSource2
01/04/2017 00:00:00 - EventSource1
01/05/2017 00:00:00 - EventSource1
01/06/2017 00:00:00 - EventSource1
30/06/2017 00:00:00 - EventSource2
01/07/2017 00:00:00 - EventSource1
30/09/2017 00:00:00 - EventSource2
31/12/2017 00:00:00 - EventSource2, EventSource3
31/12/2018 00:00:00 - EventSource3
31/12/2019 00:00:00 - EventSource3
```